# Weird behaviour in C involving unions inside structs

Tags: c

When I use unions inside structures I observed a weird bahaviour, I don't know if that should be the case or not. Basicall when you have a union with two members inside a struct for some reason I can't access both elements I only get the first one, whether I asked for the first or second member.

I wrote a test class:

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <stdlib.h>

struct uni {
  char *a;
  char *b;
};

union stru {
  struct uni unInStruc1;
  struct uni unInStruc2;
  char *test;

};

int main() {
  union stru new = {{"string 1 in A", "string 2 in A"}
                    , {"string 1 in B","string 2 in B"}
                    , "test"};

  printf("%s", new.unInStruc2.a);
  printf("%s", new.unInStruc2.b);
  printf("%s", new.unInStruc1.a);
  printf("%s", new.unInStruc1.b);
  printf("%s", new.test);

}
```

this code outputs:

```
string 1 in B
string 1 in B
string 1 in A
string 1 in A
test
```

even though in the code I'm trying to access `b` what I get is `a`. I can't access the second string `b` in any union.

When I change the initialization to

```
union stru new = {{"string 1 in A", "string 2 in A"}
                    , {NULL,"string 2 in B"}
                    , "test"};
```

Sometimes I get seg fault and sometimes the output would be:

```
(null)
(null)
string 1 in A
string 1 in A
test
```

Can somebody explain this if I'm missing something or anything

Comment: It seems like you don't understand what a union is. It can only hold one member at a time, since both members are stored in the same memory.

Comment: Accessing any member of a union but the one whose value you last set is simply an error.

Comment: Or three in this case, two of which are the same type, for which there is no reason. I can't believe the compiler didn't warn you that initializing a union like you do is meaningless. Do you have all warnings turned on?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Unless you access it with `char *` member..

Comment: @EugeneSh. `char` or array of `char`; not a pointer.

Comment: I'm surprised you could even compile this. I can't. `t.c:18:23: error: extra brace group at end of initializer` (gcc 7.2)

Comment: Which compiler are you using?

Comment: zed, You are using a non-compliant C compiler.

Comment: I think OP posted the wrong code (or the wrong output). Look at the type names. The outputs are compatible with `union uni` and `struct stru`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all what is the purpose of your code?
The memory occupied by the union will be large enough to hold the largest member of the union.  You are assigning different value to the same location and the memory location holds the last value. When you assign new values to different members, the older member values get corrupted.  In your code, you are assigning ‘test’ to union member test at the end  - so only that is not corrupted.